# Remove Fade under selected bar in TabBar Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, fade, tabbar, indicator

I want to Remove Fade under Tabbar when I select it I don't know how to remove it. I don't know about this it was Unexpected when I use `FontStyle` Bold so I want to know why when I use Bold on `TabBar`. I find the way to know the information that I know is only `softWarp` but I didn't use, but when I change font to another Weight Fade under font is disappear

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  Homepage({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

Color PrimaryColor = Color(0xff109618);

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  final List<Tab> _myTabs = <Tab>[
    Tab(
      text: 'Feed',
    ),
    Tab(
      text: 'Offer',
    ),
    Tab(
      text: 'Traded',
    )
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new Scaffold(
          body: DefaultTabController(
        length: _myTabs.length,
        initialIndex: 1,
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              Icon(
                Icons.verified_user_rounded,
                color: Colors.grey,
              )
            ],
            bottom: new TabBar(
              tabs: _myTabs,

              isScrollable: true,
              indicatorColor: Colors.purple,
              indicatorWeight: 5,
              indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(-1.0),
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
              labelColor: Colors.purple,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,

              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  fontSize: 36.0,
                  fontFamily: 'SukumvitSetSemiBold'), //For Selected tab
              unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 36.0,
                  fontFamily: 'SukhumvitSetMedium'),
            ),
            elevation: 0.0,
          ),
          body: new TabBarView(
            children: _myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
              return Center(
                child: new Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[Icon(Icons.tab), Text(tab.text)],
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: navigationbar(
            context,
          ),
        )),
      )),
    );
  }


Pubspec
 name: alpha
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  bloc: ^6.1.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  equatable: ^1.2.6
  flutter_bloc: ^6.1.1
  google_nav_bar: ^3.2.0
  line_icons: ^0.2.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.2.0
  carousel_slider: ^1.3.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - lib/assets/images/sweater.png
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I could not replicate fade issue from your code. There was no fade issue when I tried your code.

Comment: Ohhhhh maybe problem from my font ._. thank you very much. @AnilShrestha